# How do I use Bitcoin Core (fully synced) to "backtrack" a receive address?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, json-rpc, api, command-line-options

I'm trying to "reverse-track" my current Bitcoin wallet to see its exact history on the blockchain, backwards.

I have a fully synced Bitcoin Core installed.

What command do I use in its console or API to return a "backtrace" of transactions if I feed it a receive address?

I'm expecting a JSON nested arrays/objects tree with all the "actions" going back to when it was first "minted", prior to me buying it.

Comment: Are you asking about how to trace a *specific coin* back in time (ie, back before you received it, to the point where it was minted)? If so, then understand that you cannot: each transaction blends all inputs/outputs, there is no meaningful way to trace a *specific* coin through time.

Comment: @chytrik I don't know what you are saying. I think I asked my question very clearly...

Comment: @LSD Although it doesn't make sense as Chytrik explained. Do you mind sharing the reason for doing this? IT IS WRONG WAY TO ANALYZE BITCOIN TRANSACTIONS If this is about identifying mining pools and somehow associate them with transactions that are considered wrong by government agencies.

Answer (score 3):

A bitcoin transaction is composed of inputs (coins) and output (coins). As example, if a transaction has 10 inputs worth 1 BTC each, and 10 outputs worth 1 BTC each, there is no meaningful way to discern "which input become which output?", it is a nonsensical question at a technical level. Think of it as if all of the inputs are melded together, and then the outputs are forged anew from this blob.

So in relation to your question, the best you could do is to write some code to report back with a full index of bitcoin outputs that share a history with the output in question. This would mean finding the history of every input to the transaction that paid you, and every input to those transactions... and so on, until you reach coinbase outputs for every possible path.

For a lot of outputs, I think this history would likely be absolutely massive, tracing back to a large number of coinbase transactions across time. Very very few outputs would be traceable back to a single coinbase output!